# не работает git add

Tags: git

Пытаюсь добавить проект в git, создала .gitignore
произвела следующие действия:
**git init**
**git status**
**git add .**
и вот **git add .** у меня не прошел
пишет
**error: 'site_tests/' does not have a commit checked out**
**fatal: adding files failed**

site_tests - это просто папка, где у меня складируются автотесты  проекта
уже перепробовала все, что смогла и все никак
причем, добавляла обычный .txt файл и загружала только его, и все получалось, но как только пытаюсь загрузить все - ничего не выходит

буду очень благодарна за помощь в моей проблеме

Comment: `git status` что показывает?

Comment: On branch master  
No commits yet  
Untracked files:  
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  

        .gitignore
        SITE/
        site_tests/
  
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: `git add *` еще 6 символов

Comment: @РашенБеар пробовала, то же самое

Comment: @Brambuca а в гитигнор что?

Comment: @РашенБеар в том то и суть, ошибку выдает на директорию site_tests, в которой у меня директория pytest_cache, которая в .gitignore и питоновский файл с автотестом

Comment: Добавьте содержание гитигнор в вопрос. И в каких папках что лежит.

Comment: В site_tests нет других git репозиториев?

Comment: @Brambuca удали эту папку site_tests и создай заново.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh получилось, удалила и заново создала, но, к сожалению, так и не поняла в чем была проблема

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh в чем была проблема? @Brambuca а что добавилось в гит и что теперь показывает `git status`?

Comment: @РашенБеар в гит, как и долго было добавилось вообще все, кроме того, что было в .gitignore

Comment: @Рашен Беар В чем была проблема я не могу сказать, так как в данном случае непонятно, как создавался проект изначально.

Comment: удалось воспроизвести ситуацию при наличии хранилища (репозитория) в подкаталоге `.git` текущего каталога. [причём подкаталог](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-submodule.sh#L239) `site_tests` определён в нём как подмодуль. в будущем будьте внимательнее, и прежде чем пытаться создать новое хранилище (`$ git init`) убедитесь, что хранилища нет (`$ git status`).

Answer (score 3):

У меня была подобная ситуация.

У меня папка в которой лежат куча файлов. И я хочу эту папку проиндексировать. Но вылетела ошибка:
error: 'JS/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed

Что я сделал:

1. В папке JS/ у меня была скрытая папка .git/ ( которая отвечает за структуру Git-репозитория ) . Она была лишней и я ее удалил. Отмечу, что  у меня была папка .git на уровне проекта (в папке my_project), а папка .git в папке JS была лишней.
2. Затем согласно данной книги: [Pro Git: Основы Git - Запись изменений в репозиторий](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) . 
   Сказано: "Команда git add принимает параметром путь к файлу или каталогу, если это каталог, команда рекурсивно добавляет все файлы из указанного каталога в индекс.".

То есть нужно для каталогов указывать путь: 
Для меня команда выглядела так: git add C:\Users\User\my_project\JS , и все корректно проиндексировалось.

Comment: Допишите, что у вас уже была папка .git на уровне проекта (в папке my_project), а папка .git в папке JS была лишней. А то кто-то прочитает, что папка .git лишняя, увидит ее у себя в проекте и удалит.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой.
Как оказалось, я очень неудачно скопировал несколько файлов из другого проекта, и в одной из папок была папка .git.

После её удаления все заработало.